# Can I return a value just before a certain element of any array in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

let's say I've an array, I know the index of a certain element probably like this.

```
arr.indexOf(num);
```

The num is the argument of a function,and I know where it belongs by using the above code.
however I want to return the value of an element which is just before `arr.indexOf(num)`. May be something like this:

```
arr.indexOf(num)-1
```

For example,

```
var arr=[1,4,num,7,9];
```

I should return the value `4`, which is the closest element of num in that array.

Comment: Are you asking how to get an element from an array at a given index?

Comment: IndexOf(num-1), inside the parenthesis

Comment: I want the value of the element of indexOf(num-1)

Comment: @user2906838 jotadepicas just wants to say that the `-1` on your code should be inside the parenthesis for it to work...

Comment: @Gideon, ok I got it

Comment: the problem was just I was not putting -1 inside the parenthesis.

Comment: `arr[arr.indexOf(num) - 1]` perhaps?

Comment: You said you were pushing the value to the array, so maybe `arr[arr.push(num)-2]`?

Comment: Please edit your question clearly for us to aid you.

Comment: @Gideon, my problem is now solved, I wanted to return the value of `arr[arr.indexOf(num-1)]` and that was my question. For that I was just missing the -1 inside parenthesis.

Comment: @user2906838, put now your answer to this question and mark it as **answered** already!

Comment: How can I mark answered already to my answer? There is an option with "right" sign. Is that what you are suggesting?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was `-1` being out of the parenthesis.

```
 arr[arr.indexOf(num-1)]
```